# Deleting an embed on discord js is not working

Tags: discord.js

This probably has a very simple fix, but I'm a very beginner programmer so I have no clue what to do. I am trying to delete an embed after 5 seconds, and the error is saying "msg.delete is not a function" This is my code. (I am using slash commands).

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('br')
        .setDescription('Battle to the death with your friends'),
    async execute(message) {
        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('joinbutton')
                    .setLabel('JOIN BATTLE ROYALE')
                    .setStyle(1),
            );
            
            var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`BATTLE ROYALE STARTING`)
            .setColor("0090FF")
            .setDescription(`<@${message.user.id}> is starting a battle royale match. Use the button below to join!`)
            .setFooter({text: message.user.username, iconURL: message.user.avatarURL()})
            .setTimestamp()
            message.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] }).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 5000}))

       
    },
};
```

I also have code in my index.js which I don't think could be the problem but I'm just gonna send it anyway.

```
var brdb = require('./models/br')

    if(interaction.isButton())
    {
        if(interaction.customId == 'joinbutton')
        {
            var data = {
                userid: interaction.user.id,
                hp: 100
            }
            console.log(data)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is because "message" is a `CommandInteraction`, not a `Message`. You should instead use `message.deleteReply()` as mentioned in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=deleteReply).